# Asking to come up with a verse containing one line that would rhyme with a certain word

Tags: phrase-request

I have a word "box" and I want my friend to come up with a verse containing one line that would rhyme to "box", for example:

```
 "You are okay!" 
 Said Little Fox, 
 "So I will pay 
 For your small box."
```

What's the shortest and yet a clear and natural way of conveying this thought to my friend?

1) Can you come up with a poem to rhyme "box"?

2) Can you come up with a verse containing a line rhyming to "box"

3) Can you come up with a poem with the word "box" as one of its rhymes?

or how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you come up with a line whose final word rhymes with "box"?

But that's not much of an instruction. You'd need to show your friend what you have so far, so that the rhythms can be matched.

Answer (score 0):

A way to word your request is

> *(stand alone poem)*
>   Can you come up with a poem that rhymes **with** "box"?
>
> *(fits into your poem)*
>   Can you come up with a verse / stanza that rhymes **with** "box" to go with *(cite your poem)*?

You probably should add

> by using / without using box.

Comment: Can a poem / verse / stanza really rhyme with a word? I thought only a word could rhyme with another word.

Comment: Technically you are correct, but it's *implied* and would be understood that  the main rhyme would be to that word.